# How to formally greet someone in an email that I am pleased to getting to know?

Tags: greetings

When you greet someone new for the first time, you can say:

> Hello John, it's nice to meet you!

But what if you cannot greet somebody in person, when the first contact happens? For example, some other person introduces you via email and then you respond via email and want to say that you are pleased getting to know him. A formal greeting is required in this case. Is something like the following appropriate or are there better ways for saying that?

> Dear John, I am pleased getting to know you!

Is this appropriate English anyway?

---

My question is different to [Is “nice to meet you” an appropriate online salutation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28575/is-nice-to-meet-you-an-appropriate-online-salutation), because I specifically ask whether a given sentence is ok. Additionally, the referenced question discusses more the case when saying goodbye, so when the conversation is finished, where there might have been time getting to know each other.

Comment: [This question has been asked before](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28575/is-nice-to-meet-you-an-appropriate-online-salutation). (Not enough reputation to comment.)

Comment: @RileyJacob But you just did!

Comment: I am not convinced by the answers of the question referenced by @RileyJacob. Furthermore, I have specifically asked whether a given sentence is ok. Additionally, the referenced question discusses more the case when saying goodbye, so when the conversation is finished, where there might have been time getting to know each other.

Comment: @RileyJacob Sorry, I misunderstood. Well done!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Because you probably wouldn't write that. But maybe something similar like `I am pleased getting to know you!`?

Comment: @Cascabel Can you think of any introductory words for the new person before getting to business?

Comment: I don't know how to break it to you, but your question is unlikely to be reopened despite the edits. I've checked the review queue and three users have voted to keep your question closed. Maybe they didn't see any significant difference between "greet" and "salutation". I voted to reopen the question but you need another four votes. I suppose you could ask @MetaEd politely if he would reopen the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer? You wouldn't.

I don't think I have ever read anyone say in an email

> I am pleased/delighted **to meet/contact** you.

If you were writing to someone famous you could start off by saying you were

> … ***excited to write to them***.

But in the days of social media and Twitter, I think this type of polite formality is virtually obsolete.